# contenteditable overflow-x continually expanding with width: 100%

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

I have a `contenteditable div` that I want to fill 100% of its container.

The `div` has the following styles applied, among stylistic ones:

```
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
height: 480px;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: scroll;
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow-wrap: break-word
```

The issue is that the text never wraps horizontally. The `div` continues to expand infinitely once the length of each line exceeds its original width, despite `width` and `max-width` being set.

Changing the properties to an explicit quantity, e.g. `960px`, has the desired effect. The `div` remains at the defined size and horizontal text wraps inside it once the obvious end of the line is reached. I want the `contenteditable div` to consume 100% of its parent though. How do I have it fill the parent without it expanding horizontally infinitely on text entry?

Ilmiont

Comment: Set a hard value of `width` to the container. Set the `width` of the inside div to `auto`. Or better still omit it.

Comment: Thank you, it works well.  `width: 100%` on the container and `width: auto` on the `div` has worked for me. (edit: hasn't, "fix" was caused by inadvertent specific width on the `div`, will try solution above.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with

```
text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this property:

```css
word-break:break-word;
```